# Is there a StringHelper for TCaptions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Is there a unit I can add to provide a StringHelper for `TCaption`?

Using `Edit1.Text.Trim`, `Edit1.Text.ToInteger`, etc is much neater than `Trim(Edit1.Text)`, `StrToInt(Edit1.Text)`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

`TCaption` is defined as

```
type
  TCaption = type string;
```

which makes it a different type from `string` (because of the second `type`) so `TStringHelper` will not be used for `TCaption`. And there is no `TCaptionHelper = record helper for TCaption` (which would ideally be identical to `TStringHelper`).

This is very annoying in this case, but this behaviour of the language is what makes it possible for  me to define my own `TShoeSize = type Integer` and add my own `TShoeSizeHelper = record helper for TShoeSize` without losing the `Integer` helper.

I have personally suggested in the Embarcadero Jira a feature that would let you copy or inherit a record helper; in this case, you could use such a feature to tell Delphi that `TCaption` should have the same helper as `string`.

But until the language is changed -- or someone just copy-pastes `TStringHelper` into a `TCaptionHelper` -- the best you can do is this:

```
ShowMessage(string(Edit1.Text).ToUpper)
```

But beware that this is dangerous!

What if you accidentally write

```
ShowMessage(string(Edit1).ToUpper)
```

That will compile (a pointer is a pointer...).

Answer (score 5):

There is no class helper for `TCaption`, no.

`TCaption` is a distinct type from `string` with its own RTTI for DFM purposes, so the standard `TStringHelper` will not recognize it as a `string`.

I would expect a type alias like `TCaption` to have access to its base type's helpers, but alas, that is not the case. There are already reports for this issue in QualityPortal: [RSP-13736](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13736), [RSP-16486](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16486), [RSP-36474](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36474), etc.

In the meantime, the best you can do is just cast the `TCaption` to a `string`, eg:

```
string(Edit1.Text).Trim
string(Edit1.Text).ToInteger
...
```

Otherwise, you would have to write your own class helper for `TCaption` that delegates its work to the standard `string` helper.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your A until I had posted mine.